# Getting value back from dropbox.js findByName method( )?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

Before I ask this question, by no means am I a fluent javascript developer. I come from an OOP background so the whole asynchronous calls/passing methods is strange.

Anyways, I'm using the dropbox.js SDK and in particular the following method (as stated in the docs):

`(XMLHttpRequest) findByName(path, namePattern, options, callback)`

I have a **list** of file extensions I am looping through to find, calling `findByName` for each one.

```
var file_extensions = [".py", ".cpp", ".erl"];

function look_for_files(directory_path, file_extensions){
    // To hold counts for each file extension
    var count_dict = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < file_extensions.length; i++){

        var current_file = file_extensions[i];

        client.findByName(PATH, current_file, function(error, count){
            if(error){ 
                return showError(error);
            }
            else {
                count_dict.push(count.length);
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(count_dict);
};
```

As you can see, I'm simply trying to call the method each time and return that to a list called `count_dict`. However, I cannot seem to push this value into the list within the `findByName method.` I'm sure this is because I am misunderstanding callbacks and how this all works, but could someone perhaps please help?

Thank You

Comment: Are you checking that count_dict is still empty in any other way than the console.log statement at the end?  Because if not, that might indeed be an issue caused by the asynchronous nature of the request-- i.e. the code might be getting to the console.log statement before any of the callbacks have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Running this code should help you to see the issue:

```
function do_one_thing(thing, callback) {
    // Invoke the callback one second later (simulating an async network call)
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        callback('Done with ' + thing)
    }, 1000);
}

function do_things(things) {
    for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        do_one_thing(things[i], function (result) {
            console.log('Got result: ' + result);
        });
    }
    console.log('Outside of loop.');
}

do_things(["one", "two", "three"]);
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Outside of loop.
Got result: Done with one
Got result: Done with two
Got result: Done with three
```

Going back to your code, you're kicking off three network calls, then printing your empty list, and then the network calls are completing.

There are a couple options to fix this. My favorite is to use a promises library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
function do_one_thing(thing) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // Resolve the promise one second later (simulating an async network call)
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve('Done with ' + thing);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
}

function do_things(things) {
    return Q.all(things.map(do_one_thing));
}

do_things(["one", "two", "three"]).then(function (results) {
    console.log('All done!');
    console.log(results);
});
```

This way all the calls can run concurrently, but you only get results when they've all completed.

Another option is to roll your own mechanism for waiting for things to be done:

```
function do_one_thing(thing, callback) {
    // Invoke the callback one second later (simulating an async network call)
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        callback('Done with ' + thing);
    }, 1000);
}

function do_things(things, callback) {
    var results = [];
    var pending = things.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        // "index" just captures the current value of "i"
        (function (index) {
            do_one_thing(things[index], function (result) {
                // Store the results in the right place.
                results[index] = result;
                // Decrement the pending count.
                pending -= 1;

                // If we're all done, invoke the callback with the full results.
                if (pending === 0) {
                    callback(results);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
}

do_things(["one", "two", "three"], function (results) {
    console.log('All done!');
    console.log(results);
});
```

The bottom line is that since each call is asynchronous, and they may return in any order, you'll need some way to wait for them all to be finished and then provide the answer to the calling code in the form of a callback.

Answer (score 0):

`client.findByName` is asynchronous and your code doesn't account for that. The code below fixes this problem by checking the number of entries in count_dict and waits until all the network calls have returned.

```
var file_extensions = [".py", ".cpp", ".erl"];

function look_for_files(directory_path, file_extensions){

  // To hold counts for each file extension
  var count_dict = [];

  countExtensions(file_extensions, function(){
    console.log(count_dict)
  });

  function countExtensions (file_extensions, callback) {

    for (var i = 0; i < file_extensions.length; i++) {

      var current_file = file_extensions[i];

      client.findByName(PATH, current_file, function(error, count){
        if(error) return showError(error);
        count_dict.push(count.length);
        if (count_dict.length === file_extensions.length) return callback();
      });
    }    
  }
};
```

Comment: If I understand this code correctly, this will only make one network call at a time, right? This is simpler than my code below, but I think it's generally better to kick off all the async calls at once.

Comment: This version of the code kicks everything off in parallel, but I based on the timing of when each call comes back, the results can be out of order (not matching the input).